# Calculate TF for tags on a movie database python/graphab

Tags: python, graphlab

Given a number of movies with their associated tags (tags are keywords), how can I calculate the **TF** or **TF-IDF** vector for each movie? Are their ways of doing this automatically using a library in **Graphlab** or **Python**? Here is my input:

```
   print HH_tag_5K

  +---------+-----------------+
  | movieId |       tag       |
  +---------+-----------------+
  |   2324  |   bittersweet   |
  |   2324  |    holocaust    |
  |   2324  |   World War II  |
  |   357   |      Garath     |
  |   260   | Science Fiction |
  |  55267  |   large family  |
  |  55267  |    realistic    |
  |  55267  |     romantic    |
  |  55267  |   Steve Carell  |
  |  55267  |    the music    |
  +---------+-----------------+
  [194527 rows x 2 columns]
  Note: Only the head of the SFrame is printed.
  You can use print_rows(num_rows=m, num_columns=n) to print more rows and columns.
```

As the matter of fact I think `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer` is the answer for this question, but I have not yet figured out how use this for my problem? Thanks

Ref: [Link to sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)

Comment: If you're now asking for help with `sklearn`, edit the title to ask about that specifically and remove the stuff about `graphlab`. It's only the right thing to do.

Comment: Sure, but for me there is really no difference for doing this on `graphlab` or `python`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to do it with `graphlab`:

```
import graphlab
sf = graphlab.SFrame({'movie_id': [1, 2, 3],
                      'title': ['the dog is brown',
                                'the cat is brown',
                                'the mouse is yellow']})
sf['tf_idf'] = graphlab.text_analytics.tf_idf(sf['title'])
```

The `SFrame` now has another column called `tf_idf` that contains dictionaries. The keys of the dictionaries are the words in the respective title, and the values are the tf-idf scores.

```
+----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| movie_id |        title        |             tf_idf            |
+----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
|    1     |   the dog is brown  | {'brown': 0.40546510810816... |
|    2     |   the cat is brown  | {'brown': 0.40546510810816... |
|    3     | the mouse is yellow | {'is': 0.0, 'mouse': 1.098... |
+----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
[3 rows x 3 columns]
```